# Use xpath and scrapy to go through STIX files?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm hoping to use scrapy to go through STIX documents, basically setting the documents up like a RSS feed and then 'scraping' through it. 
Currently, I'm just using ipython and scrapy shell to get the xpaths.

```
<FileObj:Hashes>
    <cyboxCommon:Hash>
        <cyboxCommon:Type condition="Equals" xsi:type="cyboxVocabs:HashNameVocab-1.0">MD5</cyboxCommon:Type>
        <cyboxCommon:Simple_Hash_Value condition="Equals">C71F2F84500E6AE4485C967F72BB9E52</cyboxCommon:Simple_Hash_Value>
    </cyboxCommon:Hash>
</FileObj:Hashes>
```

I've 'scrapy' shelled to the page and I'm trying to pull out the md5 hash C71F2F84500E6AE4485C967F72BB9E52, all MD5's on the page are listed just like this.

This is what I've got but I can't get it to work -

```
response.xpath("//cyboxCommon:Simple_Hash_Value[@condition=&quotEquals&quot]/text()").extract()
```

edited below --

```
response.xpath("//*[@condition='Equals']/text()").extract()
```

this gives me all text after this, not just md5 but other STIX info which is close but still doens't work.  I'm not sure if this has something to do with the colon's in the names.

I'd appreciate any suggestions, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so apparently STIX has it's own namespace, this particular problem uses this one -

xmlns:cybox="http://cybox.mitre.org/cybox-2"

In order to grab the text from the STIX file I had to use name() or you can use local-name()

```
response.xpath("//*[name()='cyboxCommon:Simple_Hash_Value']/text()").extract()
```

or

```
response.xpath("//*/*[local-name()='Simple_Hash_Value']/text()").extract()
```

But @granitosaurus what if I wanted a compound statement?  MD5 and then then has?  I can't get this to work... let me know if you need me to open a new question.

```
response.xpath("//*[name()='cyboxCommon:Type']/[text()='MD5']/following-sibling::[name()='cyboxCommon:Simple_Hash_Value']/text()").extract()
```

Comment: I'll just start a new question for that last one.

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy Selector (or now Parsel Selector) escapes and cleans up the tags etc when creating a tree for parsing.

In your case the xpath you are looking for is:

```
response.xpath("//simple_hash_value[@condition='Equals']/text()").extract()
```

You can view the cleaned up tree simply with `response.extract()` to see how your tree looks now.

Comment: Thanks @granitosaurus, this just gives me [ ] ... I added something above which I hope helps

Comment: @mathurin68 have you checked the how does the made tree look? Can you paste your `response.extract()` results?